# ServiceM8 webhook to activity feed

Tags: service, webhooks

Is it possible to create a web-hook to listen to the activity feed in ServiceM8 ?

I have tried various objects but none are accepted when submitting the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

The Activity Feed isn't currently accessible via the ServiceM8 API.

Webhooks are only available for objects on the [REST API](https://developer.servicem8.com/docs/rest-overview).